# How do I interpret a multidimensional scaling with a linear curve?

Tags: interpretation, multidimensional-scaling, transfer-learning, feature-scaling

[image: multidimensional scaling for a fully connected layer]

For context, I have a input dataset of 156 images and I'm extracting the feature maps for each image at the last fully connected layer of the AlexNet model.

I get 156 feature maps, each of size [1, 4096]. To vectorize them, I calculated the mean across the 4096 elements and ended up with a single element for each.

I tried constructing the mds plot and got a linear curve (image shown below). I don't know what to interpret this as.

In short, is there any specific reason why a mds plot might result in a linear curve? I always assumed mds displayed clustered data points.